# facebook inside like button

Tags: php, facebook

I am tring to creat a facebook application here using TAP based on PHP.

However, I would like to make something like this.

http://www.facebook.com/BMWKorea?sk=app_187497311277576

If you see this e-commerce, there is a facebook like button in a image.

I think it has something to do with FBML, I do not know how they did it.

if this link is like button inside of it ?

i don't know .. how to like button inside ..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they included a Like button, then included their own stylesheet that applied different styles to Facebook's HTML to make the button look how they wanted. Brush up on CSS and you'll be good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

on the BMWKorea page on Facebook u see a static FBML tab. That's a old method to create Tabs/Canvas on Facebook. Actually u can't create static FBMLs tabs/canvas any more. The new way to realise Facebook Tabs is per 'iframe'. There some more options.

In both ways, regulary u can not modify the like-button. But there is a specially way to become the same effect. You have to include the Comment-Box  (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/). Then you can modify per CSS the styles of every element. BMWKorea did the same  - look in the sourcecode!

Please note, that modifying objects from facebook is not permitted in the facebook policy!!!

Here is a second interesting approach:
http://www.esrun.co.uk/blog/disguising-a-facebook-like-link/

Some more information (in german):
http://allfacebook.de/features/so-gehts-funktionierender-like-button-in-static-fbml